# digitalocean script error on call

Tags: python, linux, centos

Im Using digitalocean script on centos, however it does not seem to work.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-highly-available-haproxy-servers-with-keepalived-and-floating-ips-on-ubuntu-14-04

`Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/bin/assign-ip", line 33, in <module>
    usage()
   File "/usr/local/bin/assign-ip", line 12, in usage
    print('{} [Floating IP] [Droplet ID]'.format(sys.argv[0]))
   ValueError: zero length field name in format`

here is sh script to call

```
` export DO_TOKEN='xxxxxxxxxxx'
IP='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
ID=$(curl -s 169.254.169.254/metadata/v1/id)
HAS_FLOATING_IP=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/metadata/v1/floating_ip/ipv4/active)

if [ $HAS_FLOATING_IP = "false" ]; then
n=0
while [ $n -lt 10 ]
do
    python /usr/local/bin/assign-ip $IP $ID && break
    n=$((n+1))
    sleep 3
done
fi`
```

here is the assign-ip script

```
`#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys
import requests
import json

api_base = 'https://api.digitalocean.com/v2'


def usage():
print('{} [Floating IP] [Droplet ID]'.format(sys.argv[0]))
print('\nYour DigitialOcean API token must be in the "DO_TOKEN"'
      ' environmental variable.')


def main(floating_ip, droplet_id):
payload = {'type': 'assign', 'droplet_id': droplet_id}
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(os.environ['DO_TOKEN']),
           'Content-type': 'application/json'}
url = api_base + "/floating_ips/{}/actions".format(floating_ip)
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers,  data=json.dumps(payload))

resp = r.json()
if 'message' in resp:
    print('{0}: {1}'.format(resp['id'], resp['message']))
    sys.exit(1)
else:
    print('Moving IP address: {}'.format(resp['action']['status']))

if __name__ == "__main__":
if 'DO_TOKEN' not in os.environ or not len(sys.argv) > 2:
    usage()
    sys.exit()
main(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
`
```

Comment: Please describe what's not working

Comment: i run the sh script which executes the script below using python. the error i get is what is at the top.

Comment: I have fixed this by insalling python3 and pip3

Answer (score 2):

Just stumbled across this. I actually wrote [the Python script](http://do.co/assign-ip) above. The tutorial that it's linked from  is aimed at Ubuntu 14.04. The error that you saw was due to the fact that CentOS 6 ships with Python 2.6 while the script used a feature that is only available with Python 2.7. The [gist containing it](https://gist.github.com/andrewsomething/75a1d6acd1155013fabd) has been updated to be compatible with  with both Python 2.6 and CentOS 6.

Specifically, the error is due to omitting the positional argument in the string formatting. E.g.:

```
print('{} [Floating IP] [Droplet ID]'.format(sys.argv[0]))
```

In Python < 2.6, this needs to be explicit. E.g.:

```
print('{0} [Floating IP] [Droplet ID]'.format(sys.argv[0]))
```

[From the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

> Changed in version 2.7: The positional argument specifiers can be omitted, so `'{} {}'` is equivalent to `'{0} {1}'`.